# Why my encrypted LVM volume (LUKS device) won't mount at boot time?

Tags: lvm, cryptsetup

I'm trying to setup an encrypted volume following [this guide](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/469)

Everything is setup but mounting the encrypted volume fails at boot-time with the error:

> fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open
>   /dev/mapper/safe_vault Possibly non-existent device?

### This is my setup:

#### crypttab

```
$ sudo cat /etc/crypttab
safe_vault  /dev/disk/by-uuid/d266ae14-955e-4ee4-9612-326dd09a463b  none    luks
```

**NOTE:**

The `uuid` comes from:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/mapper/<my_logical_group>-safe_vault 
/dev/mapper/<my_logical_group>-safe_vault: UUID="d266ae14-955e-4ee4-9612-326dd09a463b" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
```

#### fstab

```
$ sudo cat /etc/fstab | grep safe_vault
/dev/mapper/safe_vault      /safe-vault     ext4    defaults    0 2
```

### What I've done...

So I went to the devoper's website and in the [Common Problems FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#3._Common_Problems) they say:

> Check that you have the device mapper and the crypt target in your
>   kernel. The output of "dmsetup targets" should list a "crypt" target.
>   If it is not there or the command fails, add device mapper and
>   crypt-target to the kernel.

So I did, turns out I don't have a `crypt` target:

```
$ sudo dmsetup targets
striped          v1.4.1
linear           v1.1.1
error            v1.0.1
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add such a target.

I think this (not having the `crypt` target) maybe causing the `crypttab` configuration to be ignored at boot-time and thus trying to mount the entry in `fstab` fails because `cryptsetup` has not mapped my encrypted volume to `/dev/mapper/safe_vault`.

**NOTE:**

The encrypted volume can successfully be manually mapped, mounted and written:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/<my_logical_group>-safe_vault safe_vault
Enter passphrase for /dev/mapper/<my_logical_group>-safe_vault: 

$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/safe_vault /safe_vault
```

This is how it looks after mapping and mounting it:

```
$ sudo lsblk -o name,uuid,mountpoint
NAME                                  UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                          
├─sda1                                28920b00-58d3-4941-889f-6249357c56ee   
├─sda2                                                                       
└─sda5                                uhBLE7-Kcfe-RMi6-wrlX-xgVh-JfAc-PiXmBe 
  ├─<my_logical_group>-root (dm-0)       1bed9027-3cf7-4f8d-abdb-28cf448fb426   /
  ├─<my_logical_group>-swap_1 (dm-1)     a40c16c4-7d0c-46d7-afc8-99ab173c20bb   [SWAP]
  ├─<my_logical_group>-home (dm-2)       e458abb7-b263-452d-8670-814fa737f464   /home
  ├─<my_logical_group>-other (dm-3)      0a1eec42-6534-46e1-8eab-793d6f8e1003   /other
  └─<my_logical_group>-safe_vault (dm-4) d266ae14-955e-4ee4-9612-326dd09a463b   
    └─safe_vault (dm-5)               9bbf9f47-8ad8-43d5-9c4c-dca033ba5925   /safe-vault
sr0
```

**UPDATE**

- It turns out that I do have the `crypt` target but for it to show up with `dmsetup targets` I had to first `cryptsetup luksOpen <my-device>`
- I've tried using `UUID`s instead according to @Mikhail Morfikov's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107859/55912) but it still fails at boot-time.

I still think the issue is that somehow the encrypted volume is not being mapped(opened with `cryptsetup luksOpen`) at boot-time thus no `/dev/mapper/<safe_vault or UUID>` exists, then trying to mount it (fstab) fails.

**UPDATE 2**

It turns out I didn't have the necessary scripts to mount at boot time. See the note in @MikhailMorfikov's answer.

Comment: Does the crypt target show up after you manually do `luksOpen`? I'd expect that if it wasn't there, luksOpen would fail too.

Comment: Ok, after `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen` two new targets appear for `sudo dmsetup targets`: `error` and `crypt`. I guess I need to change the question then...

Comment: Is it a partition or a file container?

Comment: `/dev/mapper/<my-logical-volume>-safe_vault` is a logical volume created with LVM and `/dev/mapper/safe_vault` is the device to which it is mapped by doing `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/<my-logical-volume>-safe_vault`. Do you know if `crypttab` works with LVM volumes?

Comment: I have lvm inside a luks partition, actually I have my entire 1,5TB disk encrypted (except `/boot`). All mounted at boot without a problem. Are you sure that you updated `initramfs` after editing `/etc/crypttab`? Can you show the output of `lsblk -o name,uuid,mountpoint` when everything is mounted and works as it should?

Comment: I have indeed run `update-initramfs -u -k all` before rebooting. I do this everytime I try a different configuration but so far I get the same result.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov you said you have an encrypted partition and inside it the LVM volumes. I'm trying to do it the other way around, I have an unencrypted partition `sda5`, everything inside it is managed with LVM and I want to encrypt only the volume corresponding to `safe_vault`. I have updated the question with the ouput of `lsblk`.

Comment: You have to run `lsblk` as root.

Comment: I tested the configuration -- see details in the answer.

Comment: If you like me are trying to setup encrypted root on Gentoo with systemd and dracut, make sure to **enable the `cryptsetup` use flag on systemd**. Not posting as an answer because this question is about debian, but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to pay attention to UUIDs . For instance, this is my configuration:

```
# lsblk -o name,uuid,mountpoint
├─sda2                         727fa348-8804-4773-ae3d-f3e176d12dac
│ └─sda2_crypt (dm-0)          P1kvJI-5iqv-s9gJ-8V2H-2EEO-q4aK-sx4aDi
│   ├─debian_crypt-swap (dm-1) 3f9f24d7-86d1-4e21-93e9-f3c181d05cf0   [SWAP]
│   ├─debian_crypt-tmp (dm-2)  93fc8219-f985-45fb-bd5c-2c7940a7512d   /tmp
│   ├─debian_crypt-home (dm-3) 12e8566c-8f0f-45ec-8524-6d9d9ee91eae   /home
│   └─debian_crypt-root (dm-4) 9685570b-4c9e-43ea-815e-49d10dc7a1bf   /
```

I have one encrypted partition (sda2) with 4 volumes (LVM). What I need is to set two UUIDs in the right files. The sda2 UUID goes to `/etc/crypttab` and the volume UUID (for example debian_crypt-root) goes to `/etc/fstab` .

So, it would be:

```
# cat /etc/crypttab
sda2_crypt              UUID=727fa348-8804-4773-ae3d-f3e176d12dac   none        luks

# cat /etc/fstab
UUID=9685570b-4c9e-43ea-815e-49d10dc7a1bf       /               ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro              0 1
```

After changing the `/etc/crypttab` file, you have to rebuild initramfs:

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

**NOTE**

The package `cryptsetup` has to be installed because it has startup scripts which provide support for automounting encrypted volumes at boot.

Why bother to mention this? Well, if you setup LVM during the installation Debian Wheezy installs packages [cryptsetup-bin](http://packages.debian.org/sid/cryptsetup-bin), `libcryptsetup4` and `lvm2` but not `cryptsetup`, thus you have the tools to setup LVM & LUKS devices but not the scripts necessary to mount LUKS devices at boot time. Those come in the package [cryptsetup](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/cryptsetup).

Comment: I've tried using `UUID` but I get the same error. I will update the question with details.

Comment: Hi, this is getting a bit too long, can we [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/12341/lvmdm-crypt)?

Comment: As an aside, even if you do not edit /etc/crypttab, it seems that disks will edit it for you if you alter certain encryption settings.  This answer helped me fix the mistakes I made with disks (and perhaps more mistake when trying to undo disks).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that @Mikhail Morfikov's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107859/247579) covers mounting during the *initramfs* stage.  An alternative (if it is not the root filesystem) is to decrypt and mount the partition automatically via *systemd*, after the linuz kernel is loaded.  Of course this is only possible if you are running *systemd*.  I will explain the method here:

The `/etc/crypttab` entry:

```
crypt2 UUID=e412-blahblah /path/to/crypt2.key luks,noauto
```

Here `noauto` is an instruction *not* to try to decrypt the disk during the *initramfs* stage.

Above, `e412-blahblah` is the UUID of partition containing the luks system, in my case a partition `/dev/sdb2`:

```
# blkid | grep sdb2
/dev/sdb2: UUID="e41274d8-fd83-4632-b560-ad0ba113ae75" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="5673a908-02"
```

During linuz kernel startup, *systemd* will read the `/etc/crypttab` file and create a runtime service file `/run/systemd/generator/systemd-cryptsetup@crypt2.service`.  However, that service is not automatically run.  You can run it manually

```
systemctl start systemd-cryptsetup@crypt2.service
```

but to decrypt it and then mount it during startup the `/etc/fstab` may **require** it as follows:

```
/dev/mapper/crypt2--vg-data /media/crypt-data ext4 defaults,noauto,user,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=systemd-cryptsetup@crypt2.service 0 2
```

Here `x-systemd.automount` is an instruction to *systemd* to mount `/media/crypt-data`, and `x-systemd.requires=systemd-cryptsetup@crypt2.service` is an instruction to *systemd* that decryption of `crypt2` is required before that is possible.

In the *systemd* will not actually mount the directory until the first time it is accessed, e.g. `ls /media/crypt-data`, then it will mount just-in-time and appear thereafter in `/proc/mounts`.

---

**Related**

You may ask "*why have an encrypted data disk with the key in the root file system?".  It is because the root file system is also encrypted, so the key is safe.  The root file system is decrypted during the *initramfs* stage of boot, a la Mikhail's answer.  I have another entry in the `/etc/crypttab` file for that:

```
crypt1 UUID=8cda-blahbalh none luks,discard,lvm=crypt1--vg-root
```

and I describe setting up that and a boot usb [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation/1107295#1107295)

Comment: "systemd will not actually mount the directory until the first time it is accessed" great info!

Answer (score 2):

In addition: On Debian-based systems before running `update-initramfs` command make sure that `cryptsetup-initramfs` package is installed. If not, install it first:

```
apt-get install -y cryptsetup-initramfs
```