# Grub is not booting Ubuntu with LUKS/LVM

Tags: linux, grub2, lvm, luks, initramfs

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on LUKS/LVM but unfortunately on booting I am only getting a **grub>** prompt.

```
# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0   731M  0 part  /boot
└─sda5                  8:5    0   465G  0 part     
  └─sda5_crypt        253:0    0   465G  0 crypt  
    ├─ubuntu--vg-home 253:1    0   356G  0 lvm   /home
    └─ubuntu--vg-root 253:2    0   109G  0 lvm   /
```

**Install grub to MBR and generate grub.cfg** (see [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853078/reinstall-to-existing-encrypted-partitions), [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Generate_the_main_configuration_file))

```
# grub-install /dev/sda

# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

**Grub.cfg seems to have correct LVM root volume UUID:**

```
# cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
....
set root='lvmid/MGzfKv-uhLG-wmry-Yqb2-D09r-OfKh-SDs3eb/lZDSre-QLBU-9OvM-aVrN-kR6V-DFXg-lBhRn7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/MGzfKv-uhLG-wmry-Yqb2-D09r-OfKh-SDs3eb/lZDSre-QLBU-9OvM-aVrN-kR6V-DFXg-lBhRn7'  617f84d9-1433-4620-a0c0-833fb8ce1e2f
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 617f84d9-1433-4620-a0c0-833fb8ce1e2f
fi
....

# blkid
/dev/sda5: UUID="3fbd1007-9f85-4b85-bdf2-ae55e0244bb6" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="005a4774-05"
/dev/sda1: UUID="27ca1bd4-7811-4c3a-b319-2b8dd1ce57cd" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="005a4774-01"
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: UUID="UoR32h-GB2N-GYf4-XBEP-P0rd-RrZ6-f6PK6d" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-home: UUID="0d81e74f-fe7b-4ef4-ba61-6d664d54d77c" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="617f84d9-1433-4620-a0c0-833fb8ce1e2f" TYPE="ext4"

# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 19 21:45 dm-name-sda5_crypt -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 19 21:45 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-home -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 19 21:45 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-root -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 19 21:45 dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-3fbd10079f854b85bdf2ae55e0244bb6-sda5_crypt -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 19 21:45 dm-uuid-LVM-MGzfKvuhLGwmryYqb2D09rOfKhSDs3ebHvMqdeqlhxMFcNl0XqdTRiC9sdWUmnVU -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 19 21:45 dm-uuid-LVM-MGzfKvuhLGwmryYqb2D09rOfKhSDs3eblZDSreQLBU9OvMaVrNkR6VDFXglBhRn7 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 19 21:45 lvm-pv-uuid-UoR32h-GB2N-GYf4-XBEP-P0rd-RrZ6-f6PK6d -> ../../dm-0
```

**Add sda5 UUID & volume UUID to crypttab and fstab (see [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107810/why-my-encrypted-lvm-volume-luks-device-wont-mount-at-boot-time)):**

```
# cat /etc/crypttab
sda5_crypt UUID=3fbd1007-9f85-4b85-bdf2-ae55e0244bb6 none luks

# cat /etc/fstab:
UUID=27ca1bd4-7811-4c3a-b319-2b8dd1ce57cd  /boot       ext4    defaults      0       2
UUID=617f84d9-1433-4620-a0c0-833fb8ce1e2f / ext4 defaults,errors=remount-ro 0 1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Generate initramfs (see [1](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-initramfs.8.html)):**

```
# update-initramfs -c -k all

# ls -lah /boot
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Oct 19 21:31 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  81M Oct 19 20:55 initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your LVM is on a LUKS-encrypted partition, the LVM root volume UUID will not be visible until the encryption is unlocked.

By default, Debian/Ubuntu GRUB configuration may refer to several things located on the root filesystem, including:

- font file `/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2`
- GRUB background image, e.g. `/usr/share/desktop-base/futureprototype-them/grub/grub-16x9.png` on Debian 10

If you don't want to enter your LUKS passphrase twice (once for GRUB, then again for initramfs), you'll need to make sure these are copied to `/boot` (or any other unencrypted filesystem GRUB will be able to access) and that GRUB will look for them from there.

For the font file, you can set the `GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/unicode.pf2` in `/etc/default/grub` and copy the font file to `/boot/grub` before running `grub-mkconfig`.

At least on Debian 10, the `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme` script seems to have built-in functionality to copy the background image to e.g. `/boot/grub/.background_cache.png` if the root filesystem will not be directly readable by GRUB (as in your case, as it will be encrypted). You'll need to verify that this functionality (or its equivalent in a corresponding Ubuntu script) gets properly triggered, and if not, use the `GRUB_BACKGROUND=/boot/grub/<filename>` in `/etc/default/grub` to override the background image path and copy the appropriate image file to `/boot/grub/` manually.

Note: whenever `grub.cfg` has a `set root=<something>` or `search ... --set=root` command, it is only to specify *the filesystem from which any subsequent GRUB commands will load any files*. It does not have to refer to *the root filesystem of your Ubuntu installation*: that will be specified exclusively by the `root=...` kernel boot option on the `linux /boot/vmlinuz-...` line.

In your case, unlocking the LUKS encryption and finding the root filesystem within it will be `initramfs`'s job, not GRUB's.